# jmock-2.5.1.jar vs jmock-junit3-2.5.1.jar

Tags: java, junit, jmock

What is the difference between the jars jmock-2.5.1.jar and jmock-junit3-2.5.1.jar?

Does jmock-junit contain both frameworks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the contents of `jmock-junit3-2.5.1.jar`, it just contains the JMock classes that **integrate** with JUnit. You still have to have a separate JUnit JAR.

Comment: Does it hurt to 'overload' on jars (besides making your program bigger)?

I've been adding both jars above and the junit jar to my test jMock projects

Comment: Overload as in "a large number of JARs"? If your program needs those classes, that shouldn't be a problem. Don't try to merge classes into a single JAR, just to reduce the number of JARs -- this only leads to trouble.

Comment: I meant having multiple jars that contain the same classes. I'm not sure if these jars contain the same classes or not though.

Comment: Look into them, JARs are just ZIP files with a different extension. You should definitely avoid having the same classes in different JAR files/versions around. In this case, everything should be fine.

Comment: Having multiple jars that contain the same classes can lead to problems if they contain different versions of the same classes. It's best to just avoid this possibility; these kinds of problems are hard to debug.